# C# Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, string, format

I am receiving this error on the line that reads `curPLTNOREL = Convert.ToInt32(DT.Rows[m]["PLT_NO_REL"].ToString());` below. The DataTable I am working with has 129,707 rows. `Int m` is starting at 120,603. I'm receiving this error upon the first iteration. I've tried a few different ways of converting the string to an integer, including `Int32.Parse()` and I receive the same error. The value of `PLT_NO_REL` on the 120,603rd row is `11`.

```
int curPLTNOREL = 0;

for (int m = (my511.GetEnd(4) + divisions); m < DT.Rows.Count; m++)
{
    if (DT.Rows[m]["MAIL_TYPE"].ToString() != "UNQ")
    {
        curPLTNOREL = Convert.ToInt32(DT.Rows[m]["PLT_NO_REL"].ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        curPLTNOREL = 999;
    }
}
```

I'm a bit stumped.

Comment: DT.Rows[m]["PLT_NO_REL"].ToString() is not returning a numeric string.put a breakpoint and check the value.

Comment: It's likely the value is not a numeric value.  Is it null?  You could try Int32.TryParse()

Comment: 129707? you loaded too many rows in memory, consider using DataReader instead

Comment: What is `DT.Rows[m]["PLT_NO_REL"]`? You're converting it to a string, and then to an int; why? If it's an int, convert it to an int not a string.

Comment: Remember that a `DataRow` object has an extension method [`Field<type>("ColumName")`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.field(v=vs.90).aspx). This should help with casting.

Comment: Check for extra white spaces (compare string's length with what you see - 11 - length should be 2). If the string is really `"11"` then the conversion should work. By the way, you're overwriting `curPLTNOREL` with each iteration... If this is your full code, the logic is broken.

Comment: Thank you everybody. The value I'm trying to convert is a nvarchar(6), the value is 11. When I remove the ".ToString()" it gives the error: "Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types."

Comment: well, that means that the return is null.  Or DBNull to be specific.  Check your data pull itself, because its apparently not getting the expected value.  DBNull is the value that a DBDataReader returns when the sql select that drives it returns a null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [`DataRow.Field<>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.field%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) extension method. This allows for explicit casting of a data column to a specified type. It will throw an exception if the casting fails.

```
curPLTNOREL = int.Parse(DT.Rows[m].Field<string>("PLT_NO_REL"));
```

If this throws an exception, read the exception message. It will say what type the value is, and why you can't convert it to an int.

You also need to check if the value can be null, or a non-number can be entered. If so, use TryParse().

Comment: Thank you. When I try that, it gives me the InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: Please read the ENTIRE error. This includes any inner exceptions. It should say "can't cast from <a> to <b>".

Comment: Sorry. System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
   at System.Data.DataRowExtensions.UnboxT`1.ValueField(Object value)
   at System.Data.DataRowExtensions.Field[T](DataRow row, String columnName)
   at DSHS511DebtData_Console.Program.TrayDivisions() in C:\Documents and Settin
gs\brandonh\Desktop\DSHS511DebtData_Console\Program.cs:line 640

Comment: @BrandonHall If the value is stored in the database as a `nvarchar(6)`, then there is no way that casting it as an int would work. This needs to be a string, then `Int.Parse` it.

Comment: That's so strange to me though because I've used the same chunk of code four times before this one, and it doesn't give me guff until this bit. (I'm dividing the data table into 6 parts.) That being said, I'll try changing the data type of the original field and see where that gets me. Thanks!

Comment: Changing the original data type did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As It is nvarchar type then definetly it will return a string value. and it cant be directly parse into int.